# Unable to make a select by top 100 rows query in azure synapse analytics

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-synapse

```
IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.credentials WHERE name = 'olamiss'))
          THROW 50000, 'As a prerequisite, 
          create a credential with Azure Cosmos DB key in SECRET option:
          CREATE CREDENTIAL [olamiss]
          WITH IDENTITY = ''SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE'', 
          SECRET = ''<Enter your Azure Cosmos DB key      here>''', 0
            GO

         SELECT TOP 100 *
       FROM OPENROWSET(​PROVIDER = 'CosmosDB',
                CONNECTION = 'Account=olamiss;Database=UserPortfolio',
                OBJECT = 'StoreUserPortfolio',
                SERVER_CREDENTIAL = 'olamiss'
       ) AS [StoreUserPortfolio]
```

I am trying to run top 100 rows
I think its something to do with keys but im not sure .
I am trying to make an query using the above code
but im not sure how to set it up

Answer (score 0):

To query Cosmos db in synapse analytics you have to query like this.
First, we need to create a credential containing the Azure Cosmos DB secret key. The generated script will provide you with a template.

```sql
CREATE  CREDENTIAL [pratikdemocosmos]
WITH  IDENTITY = 'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE', SECRET = '<access key>';
GO

SELECT  TOP  100 *
FROM  OPENROWSET(​PROVIDER = 'CosmosDB',
CONNECTION = 'Account=pratikdemocosmos;Database=Database1',
OBJECT = 'Container1',
SERVER_CREDENTIAL = 'pratikdemocosmos'
) AS [Container1]
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Reference:** [Setup Azure Synapse Link to Query Azure Cosmos DB Data with Synapse (mssqltips.com)](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/7509/azure-synapse-link-query-azure-cosmos-db-data-with-synapse-serverless/#:%7E:text=In%20your%20Azure%20Synapse%20Analytics%20workspace%2C%20you%20link,can%20query%20the%20data%20with%20the%20Synapse%20Serverless.)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I understand this but how exactly do i find and enter a key and identity an example would be excellent. Lets say my Identity name is IdentityName and my secret key is abcdef . Where exactly do i find the identityName and secret key